# Common Symbol to Denote this Sample Mean? [Homework Question]

Tags: probability, statistics, notation

the sample mean of $n$ Bernoulli trials can be denoted as

$$
\bar X = \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}
$$

What is another common symbol used to denote this sample mean?

**Comentary**

I'm drawing a serious blank when thinking of the answer to this question. I know that the sum of Bernoulli rv's is the Binomial distribution, it is the fraction that is throwing me off. I want to say this is similar to the parameter *p*? Also a thought is that it could be a Uniform random variable. I could use some help reasoning through this embarrassingly simple question.

Comment: You might call it $\widehat{p}$, or the empirical probability of "success" in your Bernoulli trials.

Comment: Are you still interested how $\overline X$ is distributed, no?

Comment: @callculus $\bar X$ should be normally distributed correct? The distribution is sample means is normal according to CLT?

Comment: @dylanjm Yes $\texttt{approximately}$, if the sample size is sufficiently large enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is independent of the distribution, given that you're interested in a *discrete* distribution.

**Answer**

${\cal E}[x]$, where ${\cal E}$ is the discrete expectation operator.

or ${\rm Mean}[{\cal D}]$ where ${\cal D}$ is the sample.